# C# SynchronizationContext.Send pauses UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multithreading, winforms

I have this piece of code in a WPF control (used inside a WinForms app) called sometimes from the UI thread e "often" by a secondary thread using `SynchronizationContext.Send()`:

```
private readonly DrawingGroup _backingStore;

public void Render()
{
    var drawingContext = _backingStore.Open();

    // draw rect etc....
    // drawingContext.DrawRect(...)

    drawingContext.Close();
}
```

In the default constructor of the control I take the SynchronizationContext of the UI thread:
`this.SynchContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;`

When from the UI thread the method Render() is called "more often" then it can happen that an exception is thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This object has an outstanding DrawingContext. The DrawingContext must be Closed or Disposed before making Open or Append calls.
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   in System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
   ...
```

The exception itself is clear, but I don't understand why it happens.

I added some logs:

```
private Random _rand = new Random();

public void Render()
{
    int  r = _rand.Next(); // just to "group" the logs for the same call

    _logger.debug("START {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, r);
    
    try {
        var drawingContext = _backingStore.Open();
    
        // draw rect etc....
    
        drawingContext.Close();
        
    } catch(Exception e) {
        _logger.debug("ERROR X {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, r);
        throw e;
    }
    
    _logger.debug("END {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, r);
}
```

The result is this:

```
START 1 123
END 1 123
START 1 567
END 1 567
START 1 223344
START 1 999888777
ERROR X 1 999888777
END 1 223344
START 1 876
END 1 876
```

So Render() is always executed on the same thread (UI thread), but somehow it happens that while it is in the middle of an execution another call is executed ("in parallel").

I was expecting something (an event loop) behind the scenes that at the end makes the variuos calls serialized, since it is the same thread!

In fact this seems fixing the problem, note the absence of locks:

```
private bool _rendering;
private Random _rand = new Random();

public void Render()
{
    int r = _rand.Next();

    _logger.debug("START {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, r);
    
    if(_rendering) {
        _logger.debug("Already rendering! {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, r);
        return;
    }
    _rendering = true;
    
    try {
        var drawingContext = _backingStore.Open();
    
        // draw rect etc....
    
        drawingContext.Close();
        
    } catch(Exception e) {
        _logger.debug("ERROR X {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, r);
        throw e;
    }
    
    _rendering = false;
    
    _logger.debug("END {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, r);
}
```

```
START 1 123
END 1 123
START 1 567
END 1 567
START 1 223344
START 1 999888777
Already rendering! 1 999888777
END 1 223344
START 1 876
END 1 876
```

### QUESTION 1

Can it happen that a call to `SynchronizationContext.Send()` makes somehow the UI thread "pause" what it is doing and execute the required code?

### QUESTION 2

Since from the logs I see (through `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`) that the method is called from the same thread, is it correct using "private bool _rendering" without a lock? 
(probably not because I don't know when the execution is paused, anyway depends by question 1)

Comment: `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send()` is synchronous, caused by an `Invoke()` call. So it's clearly blocking. You probably mean that the `Render()` method can be called concurrently. In that case, you have to add a lock. Possibly, have a single procedure that can access that method instead of using it in *mixed-mode*. You can change the code to use a `Progress<T>` delegate, which uses `SynchronizationContext.Post()` instead. Still need a lock if called concurrently.

Comment: Yes, the Render() method can be called concurrently: directly by the UI thread or using `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send()` by another thread. Send() is blocking, that's fine for me. Anyway I'd expect that the executions of Render() calls are serialized because they should be executed in to the same thread (UI thread), but the serialization is not happening.

Comment: Redefine your procedure. Setting `_rendering = true;` is not thread-safe. When/if it works, it would prevent the drawing from happening. Unless that's the desired result.

Comment: Making `_rendering` thread-safe is ok, but it is accessed always from the same UI thread, even if the concurrent execution happens. The `_rendering` variable is a temporary fix to the behaviour of `SynchronizationContext.Send()`.

Comment: What you see is not caused by `SynchronizationContext.Send()`, it's *caused* by different threads calling the same delegate concurrently without concern for the state. -- You haven't posted what these worker thread(s) is/are and how/when this method is actually called. Anyway, make it as thread-safe as possible (and, as mentioned, try to avoid mixed-mode calls to this method).